# How can I fix could not load file or assembly System.Reflection.TypeExtensions, Version=4.1.0.0 build on another server?

Tags: c#, wix

I am trying to create a VirtualDirectory into the IIS with Microsoft.Web.Administration dependecty. The code is calling by Wix Installer but I have the following error:

Here is my code:

```
    [CustomAction]
            public static ActionResult SetVirtualDirectory(Session session)
            {
    
    #if DEBUG
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
#endif

        try
        {
            using (ServerManager srv = new ServerManager())
            {

                string appServerPath = Path.Combine(appServerRegistryKey.GetValue("VisionServer_InstallDir").ToString(), "SDMSTools") ;

                var site = srv.Sites.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "SdmsVision");
                site.Applications[0].VirtualDirectories.Add("/SDMSTools", appServerPath);

                srv.CommitChanges();

                Configuration vDirConfig = srv.GetWebConfiguration("SDMSVision", "SDMSTools");
                ConfigurationSection staticContentSection = vDirConfig.GetSection("system.webServer/staticContent");
                ConfigurationElementCollection staticContentCollection = staticContentSection.GetCollection();

                // Check if your .ini extension exists into configuration
                var iniTypeExists = staticContentCollection.Any(m => m.Attributes["fileExtension"].Value.Equals(".ini"));

                if (!iniTypeExists)
                {
                    ConfigurationElement mimeMapElement = staticContentCollection.CreateElement("mimeMap");
                    mimeMapElement["fileExtension"] = @".ini";
                    mimeMapElement["mimeType"] = @"application/octet-stream";
                    staticContentCollection.Add(mimeMapElement);

                    srv.CommitChanges();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            session.Log("The virtual folder SDMSTools has not been created. The following error occurred: " + e.Message);
        }

        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

The virtual folder SDMSTools has not been created. The following error occurred: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reflection.TypeExtensions, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I have also this inti .csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ce35f76fcda82bad, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\Packages\firegiant-wix.3.11.20461\tools\sdk\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\Packages\Microsoft.Web.Administration.7.0.0.0\lib\net20\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

And here is my packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="firegiant-wix" version="3.11.20461" targetFramework="net47" allowedVersions="[3.11.20461]" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Administration" version="7.0.0.0" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Waters.Wix.Build.Support" version="3.0.3" targetFramework="net47" allowedVersions="[3.0.3]" />
</packages>
```

When I built this locally everything is ok, when I move this code on the server I have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add the `System.Reflection.TypeExtensions` library explicitly to your Custom Action project.

If you are using Visual Studio:

1. Open Solution Explorer and expand your project.
2. Right click **Reference** and click **Add Reference...**.
3. Find `System.Reflection.TypeExtensions` (either under **Assemblies** > **Extensions** or using Search), tick it and click **Ok**.
4. Select the newly added reference. Double-click **Copy Local** at least twice, leaving it set to **True** (to force Visual Studio to add the explicit value to the project value).

You should find that this adds something like the following to your project file:

```
<Reference Include="System.Reflection.TypeExtensions, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

When executed, your custom action should then be able to find the locally copied version of the library.